# KeyError handling python using a try/except statement?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, keyerror

I have my function here that iterates through each table listed in a different config file:

```
def DBCount(self, db_count_dict):
    schema= self.config["data-validation"]["database"]["schema"]
    unique_cols= self.config["data-validation"]["RULES"]["RULE_UNIQUE_VALIDATION"]["UNIQUE_TABLES"][self.table].split(",")
    db_count_dict[self.table]={}

    for i in range(len(unique_cols)):
        try:
            cnxn=None
            cnxn = SourceValidation.getDBConnection(self.env)
            cursor = cnxn.cursor()
            print("UNIQUE COL: "+str(unique_cols[i]))
            unique_count_query = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "+unique_cols[i]+") as unique_count FROM "+schema+"."+self.table
            df = pd.read_sql(unique_count_query, cnxn)
            db_count_dict[self.table][unique_cols[i]]=str(df['unique_count'].values[0])

        except KeyError:
            pass

    return db_count_dict
```

And here is my config:

```
{
  "data-validation": {
    "database": {
      "env": "env",
      "db-server": "ip",
      "port": "0000",
      "username": "user",
      "database": "db_name",
      "schema": "schema_name"
    },
    "allTables": "false",
    "tables": "table1,table2,table3",
    "logLocation": "log",
    "RULES": {
      "RULE_UNIQUE_VALIDATION":{
        "UNIQUE_VALIDATION": true,
        "UNIQUE_TABLES":{
          "table1": "col1",
          "table2": "col1"
        }
       }
      }
    }
  }
```

Basically, the code iterates through each column listed in the config file, doing a unique count on each column I listed. The issue is, if there is a table listed under "all tables" that isn't listed under the "UNIQUE_VALIDATION" rule, it throws a KeyError: 'table3'. So 'table3' isn't listed under my validation, but it's listed in the 'all tables' section so it's throwing a KeyError. I'm not sure if I handled the exception appropriately the way I wrote it above. I want my code to skip over the tables that aren't there instead of throwing a KeyError.

Comment: you're supposed to catch the error also when retrieving `unique_cols` variable

Comment: retrieve the unique_cols variable in the except?

Comment: you can move your try statement to enclose the whole function body